# Editing a Django Comment

Tags: django, django-comments, django-contrib

I'm attempting to edit an existing comment (i.e. replace old comment with a new one). My comments app is django.contrib.comments.

```
new_comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']

#all of the comments for this particular review
comments = Comment.objects.for_model(Review).filter(object_pk=review_id)

print comments[0].comment
#'old comment'

comments[0].comment = new_comment

print comments[0].comment
#'old comment' is still printed
```

Why is the comment not being updated with the new comment ?

Thank you.

Edit:
Calling `comments[0].save()`
and then `print comments[0].comment`, still prints `'old comment'`

Comment: `comments[0].save()` appears to save the old comment (i.e. 'old comment'), not the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't to do with comments specifically. It's simply that querysets are re-evaluated every time you slice. So the first `comments[0]`, which you change, is not the same as the second one - the second one is fetched again from the database. This would work:

```
comments = Comment.objects.for_model(Review).filter(object_pk=review_id)
comment = comments[0]
comment.comment = new_comment
```

Now you can save or print `comment` as necessary.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for explaining why my method doesn't work. 

I thought Django caches recently execute queries ? Though, I suppose that doesn't mean the queryset isn't evaluated every time I slice.

Comment: Querysets are tricky. If the full queryset was previously evaluated/iterated, then it acts like a list and slicing won't hit the db again. But in your case the qs isn't evaluated, so slicing causes Django to go to the db each time to just get the items you've requested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the value

```
comments = comments[0]    
comments.comment = new_comment
comments.save()
```

Comment: `comments` is a QuerySet. QuerySets don't have a `save()` method.

Comment: And comments[0].save() doesn't work, saves the old comment, not the new one.

Comment: Yes, this works - though I can't see why it's fundamentally different to my method. Any idea as to why `comments[0].comment = new_comment` doesn't work?