# Django :: Editing comment within the page

Tags: django

I am making a simple bbs application but I ran into a problem.

I want to be able to edit comments on the page.

At the moment, I know how to edit comments/ posts by taking the user to a different page but with comments, I think it will be a good UX if users can edit comments on the post page.

What I mean is if users click the "edit" button next to a comment, a TextField input box will come out below and users can register their comments by clicking the "submit" button next to the textfield.

How would I go about doing this?

Would this require knowledge of javascript and if yes, how would I do it?

Comment: A quick search found this: https://github.com/rhblind/django-comments-extension

Comment: Thank you for the link but at the moment, I am trying to learn and I prefer not to use something that someone else created but rather try to create the whole thing by myself :)

Comment: then this is probably what you'll be looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564023/editing-a-django-comment

Comment: Very quickly, this IS going to require some javascript and an asynchronous (AJAX like) call to update content without a page refresh.